# Simple C Program Trace-Array

Tags: c++, c

Hey guys, i'm going over a practice test for my exam tomorrow and on it there is a trace of a C program that is as follows. Need to show all output of the program.

```
int rocky[5]={1,-3,5,-7,9};

int moonman (int cloyd);
int skunch (int doofus);

int main (void)
{
   int i, sum;
   sum=0;
   for (i=1; i<3; i++)
   {
      sum=sum+moonman (i)-rocky[i]; // this is where I get lost..
                                    // do i jump to the moonman
                                    // then come back?
      printf("Sum is now %d\n", sum);
   }
   return 0;
}

int radium;

int moonman(int cloyd)
{
   int gaspar;
   printf ("Entering moonman, cloyd is %d\n", cloyd);
   radium=0;
   gaspar=skunch(cloyd*2);
   gaspar=gaspar*radium;
   printf("gaspar is %d\n", gaspar);
   radium++;
   return (gaspar);
   radium++;
   return (gaspar);
}

int skunch (int doofus)
{
   printf ("entering skunch, doofus is %d\n", doofus);
   if (radium>0) radium--;
   return (radium*doofus);
}
```

Comment: Umm, just execute the program?

Comment: I could I just don't really understand what happens. I know I can get all output but I want to know what goes on within the program

Comment: moonman(i) returns a value - so yes, you jump to the moonman function, return, and then use its return value in the calculation.

Comment: To answer your commented out question... yes, moonman(i) calls the moonman function, passing in the current value of i, the returned value from the call will then be used in the rest of your computation.

Comment: I suggest acting like a computer.  Start at "main", and go through it step by step and see what happens.  If you have a particular question when doing that, come back and ask it.

Comment: "sum=sum+moonman (i)-rocky[i]; //this is where I get lost..do i jump to the moonman then come back?" -- yes.

Comment: If you can get hold of a set of first season Rocky & Bullwinkle, you can see where some of the names came from.

Comment: thanks guys, and yes I'm aware of that. My professor is obsessed with rocky and bullwinkle, to the point where he dresses up as them and plays it on the projector during exams...

Answer (score 2):

A good way to learn what your programs are doing is to simply walk through them using a debugger:

http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~gilpin/tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

`moonman` returns an `int` value.

The line you mentioned:

```
sum=sum+moonman (i)-rocky[i];
```

Here in each loop `moonman` is called with a successive value of `i`. In this case the loop only runs twice, first with `i == 1` and then with `i == 2`. This means than on the first execution of the loop, `moonman` is called with a `1` as the parameter.

When a function such as `moonman` is called it can return a value, as in this case an `int`. So what happens in the line above is that `moonman` is called (i.e. execution 'jumps' to moonman) then the particular value calculated is returned.

Say for example `moonman` returned a value of `6`. In this case, the above line becomes:

```
sum = sum + 6 - rocky[i];
```

where `6` is the value returned from `moonman(i)`. Similarly, `rocky[i]` and `sum` are substituted with their values for the calculation.

As mentioned, using a debugger can help you easily identify how a program such as this is functioning. You should then be able to follow along and see what is happening inside the loop. Look into `gdb` and compiling with debug symbols and then stepping through code.